# Is it possible to view my WiFi CCTV camera CP Plus V21 in Ubuntu?

Tags: webcam, camera

I recently bought a CP Plus V21 Wifi cctv camera wit a sd card slot. It works through IP. I am hoping, if there is a way to view the CCTV camera output on my Ubuntu PC. Any inputs. The spec of the camera is here:

https://www.cpplusworld.com/prodassets/datasheet/9ed679ed-45db-4899-96b5-8b5c8b42025c.pdf

Comment: Try `VLC` and select "Open network stream" and enter the IP of the camera.

Comment: This did not work. In the android app, there is a username and password set for accessing the live footage.

Comment: What happened when you tried VLC?

Comment: http:// or rtsp:// username:password@192.168.x.xxx

Comment: VLC throughs error. "Your input can't be opened:"
"

Comment: Did you try the http:// or rtsp:// addresses? If they don't work, then I can't help you.

Comment: Yes, both didn't work. Unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know then. See if the manufacturer has a support forum where you can ask how to do it.